# Let's eject the [copilot]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Right now we have:

- [github-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot) - <s>no tag description,</s> contains five questions at time of asking (all about [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/), at least);
- [copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copilot) - tag description is:

  > GitHub Copilot is an AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less work.

  but none of the 27 questions seems to be about GitHub Copilot and they are instead mostly about [AWS Copilot](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-copilot/) plus a mix of [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) (by the former interns of some weird company called *"Fog Creek Software"*), [React Native Copilot](https://github.com/mohebifar/react-native-copilot), [CoPilot GPS](https://copilotgps.com/en-gb/) (I *guess*); and
- A bunch of questions [relating to GitHub Copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=github+copilot+-%5Bgithub-copilot%5D+-%5Bcopilot%5D) without either tag.

Before this gets further out of hand I'd like to suggest:

- Ban the generic [copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copilot)
- Update the wiki for [github-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot) to reflect its topic - *I went ahead and did this, there was no reason not to make it match the usage at least*
- Introduce [aws-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-copilot) and retag as appropriate
- Consider whether the more niche uses would benefit from e.g. [react-native-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native-copilot), [copilot-gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copilot-gps), ... or whether the remaining tags on those questions are sufficient for classification.

Thoughts?

Comment: "*some weird company called "Fog Creek Software"*" yes, very weird. I wonder if that company ever contributed anything to the programming world... /s

Comment: Just a commentary that there are fewer than 50 questions tagged with [tag:copilot], so it qualifies for an [abbreviated cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2756409) with the approval of one 20k+ user aside from OP here.

Comment: I agree — we should remove the [tag:copilot] tag from questions with that tag; where the question is about GitHub Copilot, add the [tag:github-copilot] tag.  I suggest not creating other `product-copilot` style tags as part of this cleanup (so no [tag:aws-copilot] tag, etc).  If they're needed, those who deal with such questions can create the tag and add it to the relevant questions.  We should also add at least a minimal tag wiki for the [tag:github-copilot] tag.

Comment: The [tag:copilot] tag has apparently existed for [12 years](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/copilot/info) without a wiki description.  It got updated in [July 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68310673/revisions) to reference GitHub Copilot.  When it was created, it was not intended for GitHub Copilot at all — but since there was no description, it is not clear what it _was_ intended for.

Comment: Just for those of you who are confused about @VLAZ's comment, Fog Creek Software is now [Glitch.com](https://glitch.com), whose team co-created Stack Overflow, created [Trello](https://trello.com) (acquired by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com)), and created [FogBugz](https://fogbugz.com) (now part of [DevGraph](https://www.devgraph.com)).

Comment: Now this is the type of quality burnination pun that I like to see :D

Answer (score 8):

The [copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copilot) tag has been removed from all questions and has already been cleaned up by the daily task that removes unused tags.

The [github-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot) tag has a good tag wiki and a few questions.

No new 'copilot' tags have been created.

At the moment, there are still questions where GitHub Copilot was causing a problem in VS Code — but GitHub Copilot was not mentioned in the question, even though it was part of the answer. I've left those questions without the [github-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot) tag.

Other than those, I believe that all the questions about GitHub Copilot have the [github-copilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-copilot) tag.